# Handling data with Azure for Android

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm building an Android app in Xamarin which has content to read, in HTML format.
I want to be able to update the content dynamically, from a client application, without the user having to download it.
For this I want to use the Azure services and store the files in a database.
However, since I have no experience in working with a database, I wanted some help and guidance on how to do this.
Should my html files be stored on the web, should I reference them in the database table?
Also, I'm not sure how to do this programatically in C#.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Normally you wouldn't store all the HTML in a database. Instead, store only the data which is going to change then use some sort of rendering engine to inject this dynamic data into your static HTML

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you meant. Why shouldn't I store all the html data in the database? And what did you mean in the last sentence?

Comment: What will your HTML files contain? Are they complete web pages or single components / elements?

Comment: They are text files converted into html. It's purpose is for reading text and maybe some images.

Comment: How does the Android app use this HTML? Is it displayed in a WebView or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it's displayed in a WebView. However, I'm thinking of maybe using ePub instead. I'm not really sure.

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow: Lots of ways to build mobile apps, whether using Azure-specific services to serve your data or some type of API you run in a web app / cloud service / vm, using any number of databases. This is an interesting discussion to have, but it's very broad and opinion-soliciting, which doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@amitairos Per my experience, I think you can combine use three Azure services to implement your needs, which include Azure App Services(such as Mobile Apps or Mobile Services), Azure SQL Database, and Azure Blob Storage, but not directly store the content into database.

As reference, there are a simple solutions in my mind, please see the steps below.

1. Making the contents includes images to the ePub files, you can try to use the tool [`Sigil`](https://sigil-ebook.com/).
2. Creating an [Azure Blob storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account-classic-portal/) and an [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/) firstly, then uploading these ePub file via the tool [`azcopy`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) and recording the ePub metadata into SQL database. The ePub metadata includes book title, ePub file url of blob storage, etc.
3. Creating an Azure App Service, such as Azure Mobile Apps as example,  list the information queried from SQL database for Xamarin Android App as web services, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ , https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-dotnet-simple/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/.
4. Offline sync the book information data for your Xamarin.Android mobile app, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data/.
5. Using the ePubReader componet to render the ePub file downloaded from your Azure services, please see https://epubreader.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I'm still trying to decide whther to use html files for the content, or ePub, since continuous reading isn't the main purpose of this app. What do you think?

Comment: @amitairos Any details of the other purposes?

Comment: It is for browsing text and books, but mainly for searching for specific info inside the text. That said, some users may want to read a lot of text at once. There are also a few other purposes for the app, but this is one of the main ones.

Comment: @amitairos I think using either html or ePub is good both for indexing from blob storage because the epub file just archive htmls and images as zip file. But using epub seems to be easier for storing and managing. In my mind, you need to create two db tables for recording book information and its related images and publish these web resources as web.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Is ePub good for searching through it? How do I do this? Also, why do I two tables? Can't I just one also for the images?

Comment: @amitairos ePub is good for storing. You need to extract the content from ePub using some libs like [`ePubReader`](https://epubreader.codeplex.com/) for indexing. As reference, you can refer to the project [`Lucene.Net`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/). I assume that a book has a html file and some images. So designing a table #1 for recording book & html metadata, not content, then designing another table #2 for recording image metadata & table #1's id as table #2's foreign key. It's more clear design.

Comment: Thanks. Will these libraries work with Xamarin on Android?

Comment: @amitairos I'm not sure whether it works with Xamarin.Android, but I think attempt is worth it. Meanwhile, trying to search for other libs on CodePlex, GitHub, etc.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you need a back-end service for your mobile application to serve HTML documents which are in turn rendered by something like a WebView.

You have a couple of options, if you want to go down the Azure Mobile Services path as you've mentioned and you are stuck on where to start, a good tutorial is available [here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/) This details setting up the service, connecting to a database and deploying to Azure.

Azure Mobile Services are geared more towards serving raw data than generating HTML documents as you're doing here. With this in mind, another option you have is to create a web application. This will be more suited to generating HTML pages. A getting started guide is available [here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/)

Lastly, in response to your question on how you should store data and transporting this to your mobile app, given you have listed C# and Azure I'm assuming you're targeting a Microsoft stack. Razor is a rendering engine, allowing you to take static HTML and inject dynamic data from a database. A good intro is available [here,](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data) I would definitely recommend a read.

Hope these help get you started, if you have more specific questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Could you explain more what each one is used for? Also, I didn't quite understand what Razor is used for, and how does this interact with my html files.

Comment: Essentially what I want, is this: A client application either on Windows or on the web, which allows the administrator to upload the document files, convert them into html, insert a Title and a cover image for the files, and upload all of that to the Azure database. Then, I want to be able to readd that from the Android app and display it as a new element, that shows the book title, the cover image, and the html content. Which tool should I use for each purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @amitairos Your original question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Now, you're asking additional questions / advice in comments, which are opinion-based questions.